# Where am I wrong ? Expo v48 build fails with gradlew error

Tags: react-native, expo, eas

I am trying to create an APK build but getting this gradlew error

[image]

Node version: 18.16.0

command used: eas build -p android --profile preview

eas.json:

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 3.14.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

end of the error file:
[image]

Here is My Package.json file.
package.json

```json
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "expo": "~48.0.18",
    "expo-constants": "~14.2.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.18.2",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.4.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.8",
    "react-native-webview": "11.26.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Comment: Provide more information. Which command you are using? Which node version ? Do you try to build an app created by an template?

Comment: Can you send the end of the error file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got this working by installing `expo-dev-client` and the strange thing is that the expo documentation had not mentioned `expo-dev-client` is required for building APK.